# Visual Studio 2008 Automatic Bracket Indentation

Tags: visual-studio-2008, indentation

I am working with visual studio 2008 and all of a sudden automatic indentation stopped working. I am not sure why. For example: if I type:

```
if(true){
}
```

it will automatically get converted to

```
if (true)
{

}
```

But now it is **NOT** working that way. The only setting I changed was Tools-> Options -> Source Control -> Environment -> Checked In Items -> Editing -> Prompt for checkout. Before it was set to "Check out automatically".

Comment: What language are you editing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you don't have something in scope that is causing errors.  Try ctrl + k + d.  If that isn't fixing your indentation, chances are you have a syntax error some place.

By the way, the settings for indendation are under Options -> Text Editor -> [YourLanguage] -> Formatting.

The option is called "Automatically format completed block on }."

Comment: Thanks Coda ! I will try that out. However there is already a check mark for "Automatically format completed block on }."

Comment: Well I found another way ! Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset All Settings and then select C#. I also saved my current settings.